# New line in MatDialogConfig (Angular)

Tags: angular, typescript

Code snippet is as follows:

```
private mDialog: MatDialog,
const dialog = new MatDialogConfig();
msg = "I love Angular.\r\n I want to code typescript."

 dialog.data = {
                message:msg 
            };
alert (msg);
mDialog.open(ABCCustomDialogComponent, dialog);
```

When I try to alert string msg. It shows the line break in the alert message window as follows:

```
I love Angular
I want to code typescript
```

However, the same message does not show the line break in dialog box. The output is as follows:

```
I love Angular. I want to code typescript
```

I tried with other tags- `br` and `div` also. However, I could not print the line break with dialog box output.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [white-space](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) css property should do the job. For this case:

```
.mat-dialog-content {
    white-space: pre-line;
}
```